# Serving admin css for django 1.5 using apache

Tags: django, apache, django-1.5

I am moving a application built on Django 1.5 to the development server, running apache, for the first time. I have it mostly running properly, but I am having issues with the CSS serving. I can either get the site's CSS working but not the admin's css or have the admin's css working but not the site's css.

I followed the documentation's and used the collectstatic command to get all the static assets into the STATIC_ROOT folder.

This is my relevant data from my settings file

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/projectmanagement/django/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     '/var/www/projectmanagement/django/projectmanagement/projects/static',
)
```

This is the relevant data from httpd.conf

```
Alias /static/admin/ /var/www/projectmanagement/django/static/admin/
Alias /static /var/www/projectmanagement/django/static/

<Directory /var/www/projectmanagement/django/static/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/projectmanagement/django/projectmanagement/django.wsgi

<Directory /usr/local/wsgi/scripts> 
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and from my vhost.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@pmt.com
ServerName pmt.com
ServerAlias www.pmt.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/projectmanagement/html/
ErrorLog /var/www/projectmanagement/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/projectmanagement/logs/access.log combined

WSGIScriptAlias /projectmanagement /var/www/projectmanagement/django/projectmanagement/django.wsgi

<Directory "/var/www/projectmanagement/html">
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/projectmanagement/html/:/tmp/:/var/www/projectmanagement   /django/projectmanagement/"
php_admin_value include_path "/var/www/projectmanagement/html/:/tmp/:/var/www/projectmanagement /django/projectmanagement/"
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I add the line

```
  AliasMatch /([^/]*\.css) /var/www/projectmanagement/django/static/admin/css/$1
```

to before the first alias in my httpd.conf file, I get the admin css to work but not the site's css. If it's gone then the site's css works but not the admin's. This has me fairly stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Adding that alias will capture *all* .css requests, but only looks capable of serving the admin css. Removing it means the css requests will reach your `WSGIScriptAlias`, and I presume you've got `DEBUG = True`... so django will be serving your static media for you.

I don't know why django's built in static server isn't working for your admin css - have you set up STATICFILES_FINDERS?

Anyway your alias really should be something like this, so it can serve all of your static files:

```
  AliasMatch /static/ /var/www/projectmanagement/django/static/
```